# Special-Pasting a hyperlink in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, copy-paste, hyperlink

Is there a way to use the *Paste Special* command to paste a hyperlink from one cell in Excel 2010 to another cell?

I am asking specifically about the *Paste Special* command, not the *Paste Link* or *Create Hyperlink* commands.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? The standard paste does this, which is the same as `Paste Special > All` command without using `paste link`.

Comment: Is the hyperlink from the function =Hyperlink() ?? Also, I don't get the reason why you would want to do this. Is there extra formatting that you don't want to come with it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. First copy the cell then select another cell, use Paste Special and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there's a way directly. But there's a workaround. If I'm understanding correctly, you want to copy and paste hyperlinks from one column to another without overwriting the values in the destination column. You just want to bring over the hyperlinks. If that's the case, then continue reading. If not, you can stop here.

First, copy the values in the destination column and paste special values them to the cells with the hyperlinks. That should essentially create the column that you want. You just have to do a regular cut/copy and paste to where you need it. If you need to preserve the original hyperlink column, duplicate it before pasting anything into it.